# Data is not getting store when moving to next step or back in stepper Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, stepper

Data is not getting store when moving to next step or back in stepper Material UI.
In getStepContent() fuction, i am returning different component like One, Two etc, and all component have material table and text field.

But when i click on next or back, data get disappeared.

See the example code:

```
function getSteps() {
    return [
      "One",
      "Two", 
       "Three",

      
      "Additional Detail",
    ];
  }

  function getStepContent(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
      return <One />;

      case 1:
        return <Two />;

      case 2:
       return <Three />;

   
      default:
        return "No data available";
    }
  }


  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();


  return (
  
      <div >
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div>
              <Paper container className={classes.header}>
                <Stepper
                  style={{
                    background: "transparent",
                    maxWidth: "2000",
                    overflow: "auto",
                  }}
                  alternativeLabel
                  activeStep={activeStep}
                  connector={<QontoConnector />}
                >
                  {steps.map((label, index) => {
                    const stepProps = {index};
                    const buttonProps = {};

                    if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
                      stepProps.completed = false;
                    }
                    return (
                      <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
                        <StepLabel
                          onClick={handleStep(index)}
                          {...buttonProps}
                          StepIconComponent={QontoStepIcon}
                        >
                          {label}
                        </StepLabel>
                      </Step>
                    );
                  })}
                </Stepper>
```

Comment: can you add some code sandbox to this example reproducing waht u want?

Comment: Right... sure man

Comment: data has nothing to do with material UI. you are probably not sending it properly. I also recently starting learning React JS and ran into similar issues. before you start using themes, spend some time building simple components and experiment with sending and returning data, and also contexts. Then, start using themes. directly using themes built for commercial use will only confuse you, instead of helping you.